# How to get encoded version of string (e.g. \u0421\u043b\u0443\u0436\u0435\u0431\u043d\u0430\u044f)

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

How to get encoded version of string  (e.g. \u0421\u043b\u0443\u0436\u0435\u0431\u043d\u0430\u044f) using Java?

EDIT:
I guess the question is not very clear... Basically what I want is this:

Given string **s="blalbla"** I want to get string **"\uXXX\uYYYY"**

Comment: Your edit is not an edit. It is a new question.

Comment: You have tagged this UTF-8, so do you want UTF-8?  Or do you want UCS-2 (which is not a valid Unicode encoding) code units instead of proper logical Unicode code points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to extract each code point/unit from the String and encode it yourself. The following works for all Strings even if the individual linguistic characters within the String are composed of digraphs or ligatures.

```
public String getUnicodeEscapes(String aString)
{
    if (aString != null && aString.length() > 0)
    {
        int length = aString.length();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < length; ctr++)
        {
            char codeUnit = aString.charAt(ctr);
            String hexString = Integer.toHexString(codeUnit);
            String padAmount = "0000".substring(hexString.length());
            buffer.append("\\u");
            buffer.append(padAmount);
            buffer.append(hexString);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above produces output as dictated by the Java Language Specification on [Unicode escapes](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.3), i.e. it produces output of the form `\uxxxx` for each UTF-16 *code unit*. It addresses supplementary characters by producing a pair of code units represented as `\uxxxx\uyyyy`.

The originally posted code has been modified to produce Unicode codepoints in the format `U+FFFFF`:

```
public String getUnicodeCodepoints(String aString)
{
    if (aString != null && aString.length() > 0)
    {
        int length = aString.length();
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(length);
        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < length; ctr++)
        {
            char ch = aString.charAt(ctr);
            if (Character.isLowSurrogate(ch))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                int codePoint = aString.codePointAt(ctr);
                String hexString = Integer.toHexString(codePoint);
                String zeroPad = Character.isHighSurrogate(ch) ? "00000" : "0000";
                String padAmount = zeroPad.substring(hexString.length());
                buffer.append(" U+");
                buffer.append(padAmount);
                buffer.append(hexString);
            }
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The gruntwork is done by the [String.codePointAt()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29) method which returns the Unicode codepoint at a particular index. For a String instance composed of combinational characters, the length of the String instance will not be the length of the number of visible characters, but the number of actual Unicode codepoints. For example, `क` and `्` combine to form `क्` in Devanagari, and the above function will rightfully return `U+0915 U+094d` without any fuss as `String.length()` will return 2 for the combined character. Strings with supplementary characters will be with single codepoints for the individual characters -  (the page will not display this String literal correctly, but you can copy this just fine; it should be `Javascript` but written using the supplementary character set for [Mathematical alphanumeric symbols](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D400.pdf)) will return  `U+1d4a5 U+1d4b6 U+1d4cb U+1d4b6 U+1d4c8 U+1d4b8 U+1d4c7 U+1d4be U+1d4c5 U+1d4c9`.

Comment: **That code is wrong!** First, it won’t even compile because `string` should be `aString` in the function.  Second, it has the UTF-16 bug because it forgot to do `if (aString.codePointAt(ctr) > Character.MAX_VALUE) { ctr++; }  // UG!`. Just try it on something like `""` to see what I mean. That’s the string containing the nine (but not eighteen!!) Unicode characters `U+1D4A5 U+1D4B6 U+1D4CB U+1D4B6 U+1D4C8 U+1D4B8 U+1D4C7 U+1D4BE U+1D4C5 U+1D4C9`. As for combining characters, Java has no proper grapheme support, so there you’re just hosed.

Comment: Well done. I loathe the whole code unit thing in Java; it’s a terrible awful mess. Remember the refrain: *int is the new char*. We really and truly need a UString class that works correctly on Unicode code points, so `length()` returns their count, etc.  Too bad we can’t subclass `String` or change the compiler’s literals. These seem unfixable, a curse. BTW, [George Doursos’s Symbola font](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) will let you see the math letters and a lot more.

Comment: You can look at slide 5 on “Astral Projections” from my [OSCON Unicode Support Shootout](http://training.perl.com/OSCON2011/index.html) talk to see that the math letters are the most commonly occurring non-BMP codepoints (I hate the phrase “supplemental characters” in Java because it suggest they forgot some; it’s Java who forgot them and didn’t stick with the standard) in a real all-English corpus, this the PubMed Central Open Access collection.

Comment: Yeah, Java needs a separate class to handle operations on codepoints, and possibly another to handle operations on linguistic characters so that even concepts like codepoints can be ignored by folks who want to work on combined characters in languages.

Comment: If you mean extended grapheme clusters, then yes.  Even `vim` knows about them. You’d think Java would, but it doesn’t.  If you use the Android wrappers to JNI into the ICU regex class, you get `\X` for an EGC.  The other ICU classes don’t require JNI. All are incomparably superior to anything OraSun pawns off on us.  And I don’t even like ICU: it’s big and heavy and awkward. But it works, and it works according to The Unicode Standard, something that Java is at best super-dodgy at.

Comment: too much info for me, I am not even following your discussions. Have to read it up...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    CharsetDecoder decoder = charset.newDecoder();
    CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();

    try {
      ByteBuffer bbuf = encoder.encode(CharBuffer.wrap("\u0421\u043b\u0443\u0436\u0435\u0431\u043d\u0430\u044f"));

      CharBuffer cbuf = decoder.decode(bbuf);
      String s = cbuf.toString();
      System.out.println(s);
    } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: given a string s I would like to get its encoding

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a build-in solution, so:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i<yourString.length(); i++) {
    builder.append(String.format("\\u%04x", yourString.charAt(i)));
}
String encoded = builder.toString();
```

Edit: sry, I thought you wanted to get the String encoded to \uXXXX expressions ...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't saying what encoding you are after, but based on the tag I'm assuming you want the UTF-8 encoding.  Here's how:

```
byte[] utf8 = 
    "\u0421\u043b\u0443\u0436\u0435\u0431\u043d\u0430\u044f".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

You can then write a simple loop to output the bytes in `utf8` in hexadecimal or decimal ... or do something else with them.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println ("\u0421\u043b\u0443\u0436\u0435\u0431\u043d\u0430\u044f");
```

works like a charm for me:

```
Служебная
```